# How to show a set is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let $C[0,2π]$ be the vector space of continuous functions defined on $[0,2π]$

For $n = 1,2,\ldots $, let $f_n ,g_n ∈ C[0,2π]$ be given by

$$f_n(x) = \cos(nx)$$

$$g_n(x) = \sin(nx)$$

(i) Show that $\{1, f_1 ,g_1 ,\ldots, f_n ,g_n,\ldots\}$ is an orthogonal set

(ii) Turn the above set into an orthonormal set

I am having trouble on how show that the set for (i) is orthogonal

I did: $$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)\sin(nx)\,dx = \frac{\sin^2(2\pi n)}{2n}$$

Now for each value of $n$, this evaluates to $0$, and we know that $u$ if orthogonal to $v$ if $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$

Would this be enough to show that the set if orthogonal?

For (ii) would multiplying each vector $v$ in the orthogonal set by $1/\|v\|$ give me an orthonormal set?

Comment: For (i) you need to show that $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx =0$ and similarly for $\sin$'s (when $m\neq n$) since you require all $f_n,f_m$ and $g_n,g_m$ pairs to be orthogonal too. Also, though rather trivial you need $\langle f_n,1\rangle,\langle g_n,1\rangle=0$ for all $n,m$. Other than these your solution looks fine

Comment: You've only showed a subset of the set is orthogonal. As in you've showed that $f_n$ is orthogonal to $g_n$, but for example haven't shown that $f_n,f_m$ are orthogonal $n\neq m$. Similarly for $g_n, g_m$ and $f_n, g_m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very similar question
http://ms.mcmaster.ca/courses/20102011/term4/math2zz3/Lecture1.pdf